# Reset function with checkboxes in Struts 1.3

Tags: struts, reset, struts-1

I've got a problem. I heard something about the Struts reset function but I never see any example and I don't know how to write it.

I heard it can help when I have such a case:

I have few checkboxes checked, then in my form I click next and go to next page, then I click back and go again to the page with checkboxes, uncheck few of them and check the others and click next again. Then, validation errors appear as if I those checkboxes which I unchecked were still checked.

Do you know how to use it in this case?

Comment: To add to Roman's answer, it's also used for non-session-scoped forms so that checkboxes in particular are initialized to their correct values. This works around normal browser behavior which includes not sending unchecked checkboxes. Hidden fields can also handle this.

Answer (score 0):

In the action form you can override the [`reset()`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts1/tags/STRUTS_1_2_9/legacy/api-1.1/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html#reset(org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)) method and initialize the checkbox property value to its default state. This only needed if your action form is session scoped. Thus it could contain values of the unchecked checkboxes before you submit or reset button pressed.

You can see the example [Struts `<html:checkbox>` checkbox example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-htmlcheckbox-checkbox-example/).

Comment: Should I only implement the reset function? Nothing more? It will be invoked automatically? I did it and nothing happens.

Comment: See the link to a checkbox example.